# create a custom function with body in dao room database

Tags: android, dao, android-room

I want to create a DAO Object with a custom function like this

```
@Dao
interface DataAccessObjDao{
    @Insert
    fun insert(someEntity: SomeEntity)

    @Ignore
    fun sampleFun(){
        insert(SumEntity())
    }

}
```

but compiler complains about sample fun

*Class 'DataAccessObjDao_Impl' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'sampleFun()' in 'DataAccessObjDao*

Comment: yes it must be,actually it's not my original implementation

Answer (score 6):

`@Ignore` is for property or entity, can not be used on a method.
You can do this by extending your interface :

```
fun DataAccessObjDao.sampleFun(){
    // irrelevant code
}
```

or by adding `@Transaction`

```
@Transaction
fun sampleFun(){
    firstDelete()
    thenInsert()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, Dao can also be abstract class. You can define a method with body inside abstract class. However Dao is for querying tables and have different Dao objects for different tables. It would be better if they had only insert, delete, update and select queries. I also BaseDao to minimize Dao code.

You should call dao.insert(SumEntity()) inside a LocalDataSource class which you use Repository like in [this guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide).